# Why does Samsung Magician write so much data

Tags: windows-10, ssd, logging, process-explorer, samsung-ssd

I've installed a Samsung SSD recently and have been keeping an eye on the total data written from the Magician dashboard (7.0.0.510). In doing so over the past few days I've notice it jumping about 20 GB a day when I would check. This seemed rather high, and consistent.

So to determine what processes were writing so much data I installed Process Explorer, which revealed that it was in fact Magician itself. The below screen shots were taken in roughly one minute intervals while the Magician UI was open. It was writing about 20 MB a minute, which is about 1.2 GB an hour. This occurs even with "Dashboard History Option" turned off in settings. Also, Magician shows minimal write activity when the UI is either closed or minimized and, but it's process (and service) still running, and it's system tray icon active:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why a "reporting" tool would need to write so much data I'm unsure of, especially in light of the fact that reporting primarily involves reading and displaying values. Being that these drives have a limited life based on write volume (TBW), I find it rather peculiar that the proprietary reporting software is seemingly wasting valuable writing capacity. I was also unable to find any other logging history options to toggle (though haven't dug deeper than the UI).

Comment: You are aware your SSD is capable of writing TBs worth of data for years before it reaches it's lifespan on write, right?  The application most likely isn't actually writing that much data.

Comment: @Ramhound 20 MB / min * 60 min = 1,200 MB = 1.2 GB. It's a waste regardless. I didn't pay top dollar for a "Pro" drive for it to be wasted by its own reporting utility... And yes, 1200 TB supposedly

Comment: So uninstall the reporting tool unless you need it.  However, I still say something else is going on, I would have to look at my own system to verify.

Comment: @Ramhound Just did. HWInfo can read SMART and report TBW just as well

Comment: @Ramhound 970 Pro is unnoticeable faster than 970 Evo btw, as I figured it would be, but needed a larger drive anyway and didn't want to get stuck with the non-Phoenix controllers that are now in the 970 Plus: [Samsung seemingly caught swapping components in its 970 Evo Plus SSDs](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/08/samsung-seemingly-caught-swapping-components-in-its-970-evo-plus-ssds/), and "normal" 970 Evo's are tough to find

Comment: See also: [Identifying SSD Controller and NAND Configuration](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2019/01/identifying-ssd-controller-and-nand-configuration/)

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? I am very familiar with Samsung devices. **Arstechna is a trash website moderated by idiots who couldn’t remove a paper bag off their head.**

Comment: @Ramhound Its all the same, from every company I deal with. GM with their numerous, trivial and costly part failures, Dell with their out-of-the-box-configured-to-overheat XPS's, Bosh dishwashers that default to a 2.5 hour wash cycle, when the "Express" 40 minute cycle is more than adequate. The pattern continues, and gets worse with greed. Just sick of paying for all of this crap this designed to fail after a few years that you cant even get parts for half the time b/c they want you to buy the next model. Will only get worse throughout recession. So, that's what it has to do with.

Answer (score 3):

The life is based on data written to the flash, not I/O performed by the CPU to the SSD. You are comparing two measurements of completely different things.

For example if Magician performs a status request operation to the SSD every second, a lot of I/O bytes will be written to the SSD. But *none* of the SSD's write life will be consumed.

The tool you are using is measuring the use of your computer's I/O bandwidth, not the amount of data the SSD's controller is writing to flash.

Comment: I'll have to look into this distinction further. I just know that both HWInfo and Magician are both reporting the same "Total Writes" value, in GB, and it's steadily increasing every day. I suppose looking in the actual SMART value that they are both reading from the drive/controller should determine what the value actual means.

Comment: The screenshots you showed depict CPU I/O bytes, regardless of whether it's commands, control information, or data stored on flash.

Comment: Understood, however still uncertain if the data is controller or disk bound. I have uninstalled Magician and will keep a watch on "Total Bytes Written" from HWInfo to see in its rate of growth decreases.